# Embedding Tag Files in a JAR

Tags: jsp-tags, tagfile

Is it possible to do this? What I'm trying to accomplish here is the creation of an extensible Struts 2 plugin with customizable screens to avoid code duplication in similar projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it has nothing to do with Struts 2:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html#wp90207 (under "Packaged Tag Files").

Here is an example: http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=473

Comment: examulator source is really good. Upvoted and added a description in case its URL changes and the community is devoid of its contents ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting steps from [this](http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=473) source(taken from prev. answer) in case URL changes. (Simplest solution I found on the internet)

> When wrapped in a jar (Java archive) tag files require a **tld**.

**menu.tld** placed in the `META-INF` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN"
                           "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>menutagfile</shortname>

    <uri>www.examulator.com/menutagfile</uri>
    <tag-file>
        <name>menu</name>
        <path>/META-INF/tags/menu.tag</path>
    </tag-file>
</taglib>
```

**menu.tag** placed in the `META-INF\tags` directory.

```
<%@ tag body-content="tagdependent" %>
<%@ attribute name="menutext" rtexprvalue="true"%>

<h1>This is my tag file</h1>
<jsp:doBody/>
```

The command to package these into JAR(Auto package in case of `maven`)

```
Jar cvf menutagfile.jar .\META-INF\*.*
```

Usage in the parent project

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mytagfile" uri="www.examulator.com/menutagfile" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demonstration of Tag Files</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> What is going down? </h1>
<mytagfile:menu/>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note*: In case you do not have a META-INF folder in your project, create one inside `src/main/resources`.

Comment: this is only one way of doing it. Another, arguably more common, is to compile those tag files as java classes.

Comment: Also, directory `src/main/resources` is specific to maven. If you're not using maven (or gradle configured that way), then that advise is not applicable.